# Are typed lists unpythonic?

Tags: python, properties

I come across this problem a lot and I never know what the best, and most pythonic, way of solving it is.

Say I have a class where one of the properties is a list. The list is stored internally and, instead of accessing the list directly, users are asked to interface with the list via a set of methods provided by the class. Consider the code example below:

```
from validation.check import Check


class Validator(object):
    """
    Class used to perform validation.
    """

    def __init__(self):
        self._checks = []

    def add_check(self, check):
        """
        Add the given check to the validator.

        :param check: Check instance.
        :type check: :class:`validation.check.Check`

        :raises TypeError: When given value is not a validation.Check
        """
        if not isinstance(check, Check):
            msg = 'Check item must be type "{0}". Got "{1}"'
            msg = msg.format(Check.__name__, type(check).__name__)
            raise TypeError(msg)

        self._checks.append(check)

    @property
    def checks(self):
        """
        Get validator checks.
        """
        return self._checks
```

In this case the `add_check` method does a type check on the value before adding it to the list, but you might put all kinds of extra functionality within the `add_check` method.

The `checks` property allows users to inspect the list of checks. However, it also allows users to modify the checks list without using the `add_check` method. For example:

```
validator = Validator()
validator.checks.append('BogusValue')
```

Now I have an invalid value in my `checks` list because the `add_check` method as bypassed. What is the best, and most pythonic way of solving this?

Some people suggest returning a copy of the internal list.

```
    @property
    def checks(self):
        """
        Get validator checks.
        """
        return list(self._checks)
```

In this case, modifying the copy would not affect the `checks` list stored internally by the `Validator`. I can see how this solves the problem but I think it may cause confusion in some cases.

Some people suggest returning a `tuple` or creating a read only list:

```
import collections


class ReadOnlyList(collections.Sequence):
    def __init__(self, items):
        super(ReadOnlyList, self).__init__()
        self._items = items

    def __getitem__(self, index):
        return self._items[index]

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self._items)
```

Returning the read only list from the `Validator.checks` property would prevent users from modifying the `checks` list directly.

```
    def checks(self):
        """
        Get validator checks.
        """
        return ReadOnlyList(self._checks)
```

If I go to the trouble of creating a custom list object, why not build the type check into a custom list object? For example:

```
import collections


class Checks(collections.MutableSequence):

    def __init__(self, items):
        self._items = []
        for index, item in enumerate(items):
            self.insert(index, item)

    def _validate_item(self, item):
        if not isinstance(item, Check):
            msg = 'List item must be type "{0}". Got "{1}"'
            msg = msg.format(Check.__name__, type(item).__name__)
            raise TypeError(msg)

    def __getitem__(self, index):
        return self._items[index]

    def __setitem__(self, index, item):
        self._validate_item(item)
        self._items[index] = item

    def __delitem__(self, index):
        del self._items[index]

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self._items)

    def insert(self, index, item):
        self._validate_item(item)
        self._items.insert(index, item)
```

Then I could remove the `add_check` method altogether because the type check is built-in to the `Checks` object.

```
class Validator(object):
    """
    Class used to perform validation.
    """

    def __init__(self):
        self._checks = Checks()

    @property
    def checks(self):
        """
        Get validator checks.
        """
        return self._checks
```

Finally, some people suggest that all of the above is overkill and that well documented code should be enough to prevent users from adding checks in a way that is not intended.

Perhaps they are all valid solutions? I have a great deal of trouble choosing an approach and sticking to it in this case. If anyone feels strongly about this issue, I would love to hear your thoughts.

Many thanks.

Comment: I would use name mangling `self.__checks`, the user would have to really go out of their way to access it directly

Comment: I voted to close this as primarily opinion based - but the most pythonic solution is indeed to cleary document what a "Check-like" object should be and call it  day.

Comment: Python's philosophy: «We are all consenting adults» and remember duck typing is not possible with your style of coding.

Comment: I upvoted this as an interesting / useful question but @brunodesthuilliers is correct that the question is opinion-based. It *may* be suitable for https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic